# Access Employee ID in google-admin-sdk

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am currently working on a simple Java application to query my organization's G Suite users.  I am using the Google-provided Java API (Directory API).  I am currently able to pull users, and their corresponding attributes using statements like the following:

```
String firstName = user.getName().getGivenName();
String lastName = user.getName().getFamilyName();
String email = user.getPrimaryEmail();
```

However, I do not know how to access attributes such as **Employee ID, Employee type, department and title**? I do not see any functions similar to the ones that I use to access first name, last name etc.

How do you access these values using the Java API?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the properties you're looking for in [Users Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users). Employee ID is under externalIds:

> externalIds string  A list of external IDs for the user, such as an
>   employee or network ID.

Comment: I know that this is possible to do using HTTP requests directly, by my project uses the Java API provided by Google. In the documentation, I see that there is a function.... getExternalIds() (for employee id?) or getOrganizations()  (for department?).  However I am unsure of how to use these functions.  Is there an example?   The Employee ID, Employee type, department and title are not custom fields-- they are built into the G Suite/Google Apps admin console by default.  Thank you.